# Escaping LaTeX tokens in addresses for printing one label printer that can cut

Tags: detokenize

I am trying to print addresslabels on a Brother_QL_820NWB, which is a label printer, that can cut the paper. I have a small script, that gathers the address data from user input and than calls my LaTeX file. The userinput leads to following problems (I could solve two of):
a.) Some company names are too long for the default choosen font: I managed this by using a small LaTeX script I found here that changes to smaller fontsizes, until the text fits.
b.) I wanted to cut the paper as close as possible: I use pdfcrop to solve this.

This all worked, but I could not find a way to escape the problems with e.g.
Fish & Friends company

Which for sure gives a LaTeX error when the & is parsed and not escaped before. I was hoping to solve my problem with `\detokenize` but I do not know how.

The userinput is "collected" in the `\addresslabel` in the following matter and given to latex as

```
pdflatex \def\addresslabel{Fish \& Friends \$\%üäöÜÄÖß\\John Doe\\Whateverstreet 123\\12345 Town\\country\\}\input{shipment-label.tex}
```

So how could the above be printed while keeping the single lines? I could exchange the \ to anyting else, if this makes things easier.

Many thanks
Juergen

Comment: sorry but from your line it is quite impossible to say why this should error.

Comment: My problem is, that I do not have any idea on how to use `\detokenize˚ and to have single address lines.
I tried all combinations I could find of with
\detokenize\expoandafter\addresslabel with braces, ... 

``` 
\documentclass{article}

\def\addresslabel{%
Fish \& Friends \$\%üäöÜÄÖß\\
John Doe\\
Whateverstreet 123\\
\ \\
12345 Town\\
country\\
}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\detokenize\addresslabel

\end{document}
```
should "simply" print the lines below each other.

Sorry, I do not knwo why ``` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax with \detokenize would be `\detokenize\expandafter{\addresslabel}`,
But in your example you wouldn't need it (or it would give wrong output), and you will always get into problems with the percent char.

It would probably make more sense to give some of the special chars the catcode other:

```
{\catcode`\%=12 \catcode`\&=12 \catcode`\$=12 \gdef\addresslabel{Fish & Friends $\%üäöÜÄÖß\\ John Doe\\ Whateverstreet 123\\ \ \\ 12345 Town\\ country\par}}
 
 \documentclass{article} 
 
 \begin{document} 
 \addresslabel 
 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: The above solutiuon (using the catcodes directly) works perfect and is exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which operating system you use, or which terminal if you use Linux. Assuming Bash in Linux you need to escape `\\` and quote the whole input. Note that you *don't* need to escape the slash in `\&` and `\%` or for command sequences like `\addresslabel`, but you *do* need it for `\\$`.

```
$ pdflatex "\def\addresslabel{Fish \& Friends \\$\%üäöÜÄÖß\\\\John Doe\\\\Whateverstreet 123\\\\12345 Town\\\\country\\\\}\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\addresslabel\end{document}"
```

Result:

[image]

Indeed as mentioned in a comment a simpler way is to use single quotes and not escape backslashes:

```
$ pdflatex '\def\addresslabel{Fish \& Friends \$\%üäöÜÄÖß\\John Doe\\Whateverstreet 123\\12345 Town\\country\\}\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\addresslabel\end{document}'
```

Comment: or use single quotes to avoid doubling backslashes

Comment: @plante that is indeed much simpler, edited.

Comment: Oh, now the question makes much more sense, I hadn't considered that it could be about a quoting problem.